# Is there any way to scan BLE devices in background without explicity specify the serverUUIDs?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process, core-bluetooth

My goal is to scan over time all the BLE devices. In foreground this is possibile, but as soon as I close the app it does not scan anymore. In the swift documentation it is written:

> Your app can scan for Bluetooth devices in the background by specifying the bluetooth-central background mode. To do this, your app must explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the serviceUUIDs parameter.

My question is if there is any way to get around the constrain and scan them as much as possibile. For my purpose I do not have to connect to them, I just need to find them.

One of my approaches was to dinamically populate the array of serviceUUID, but I could not do it because I actually do not know the devices that I'm going to scan.

Comment: If you don´t have the UUID you cannot scan for them in the backgrounnd. This is intended to reconnect known devices and not scannig for new ones.

Comment: Even if you populated the service uuids, the other restriction on background scanning is that the duplicate scan key is ignored, so you will not receive discovery notifications for a peripheral that has been discovered previously